# How to concatenate string in firestore rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have groupMemberships object in which docId is a combination of groupId and userId. I made it like that because is easy to scale. Here is a code snippet of how I'm trying to do concatenation I tried many ways but nothing works:

```
  match /comments/{document=**} {
      function checkIfHasMembership(groupId, userId) {
        // Construct the document path using string concatenation
        let groupMembershipPath = 'groupMemberships/' + groupId + userId;
        let groupMembershipDoc = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(groupMembershipPath)).data;
        return groupMembershipDoc.userId == userId;
      }
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if checkIfHasMembership(resource.data.groupId, request.auth.uid);
    }
```

I tried different way of concatination even with interpolation nothing works.

Comment: Does it work with `let groupMembershipPath = groupId + userId;
    let groupMembershipDoc = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groupMemberships /$(groupMembershipPath)).data;ˋ (I’m commuting and cannot test)

Comment: It's not working like that I already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings do have concatenation with `+`, according to the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String).

The problem is likely how you are building the document path without specifying each path component separately.  Try expressing the [path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Path) of the document like this instead:

```
let groupMembershipId = groupId + userId;
let groupMembershipDoc = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groupMemberships/$(groupMembershipId)).data;
```

Comment: This not working. This is what I tried first.

Comment: Maybe you should edit the question to show the actual data and app code you're working with. The rule itself is meaningless without that context.  There could be a problem in your client app, or maybe the data doesn't match.  We can't tell, which means we can't reproduce the issue as you see it.

Comment: The problem is let groupMembershipId = groupId + userId; for example if I do something hardcode actual id like groupMembershipId = "fdsfdsfdsfsd" it's working perfectly.

Comment: The API documentation says that strings have concatenation, so maybe you should file a bug with Firebase support.

Comment: For some reason is not working on rules. I think it's because of security reasons due to injections.

Comment: I figured out. The problem was not the concatenations. It was the way I retrieved the `resource.data` for the write rule should be retrieved like `request.resource.data.groupId`